# I want to perform HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) using Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I would like to stream web cam video to http web page. I know how to read from web cam and archive it to file.

But how to stream via web. What is the pipeline for that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `hlssink` element from [gst-plugins-bad](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/ext/hls):

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink
```

It will generate playlist and segments files. You need to provide HTTP access to these files, you can use any webserver, **nginx** or **Apache**, for example.

You can tweak `hlssink`'s parameters to specify target location, segments count, etc. All options can be listed with:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 hlssink
```

If you need better low-level control, you'd better create your own web server with **libsoup**, manually split MPEG-TS into segments and add your own playlist endpoint.